# Toggling a class on click in Slick slider

Tags: javascript, html, css, slick.js

I am trying to change the styling of Slick slides by toggling a class on the 'click' event. But for some reasons, I am not getting normal behavior, i.e the styling of some slides doesn't change on click, but instead changes when you scroll them horizontally.

You can check the webpage at my Github: https://bilalarshad24k.github.io/inspocreate/

Here is the code:

**HTML**

```html
    <div class="slickSlider col-sm-12 px-5" dir="ltr">
        <button type="button " class="btn item categItem my-1 ">
            <p>Business</p>
        </button>
        <button type="button " class="btn item categItem my-1 ">
            <p>Empowerment</p>
        </button>
        <button type="button " class="btn item categItem my-1 ">
            <p>Life Style</p>
        </button>
        <button type="button " class="btn item categItem my-1 ">
            <p>Confident</p>
        </button>
        <button type="button " class="btn item categItem my-1 ">
            <p>Fashion</p>
        </button>
        <button type="button " class="btn item categItem my-1 ">
            <p>Office Dress</p>
        </button>
        <button type="button " class="btn item categItem my-1 ">
            <p>Infotainment</p>
        </button>
        <button type="button " class="btn item categItem my-1 ">
            <p>Success</p>
        </button>
        <button type="button " class="btn item categItem my-1 ">
            <p>Women Empowerment</p>
        </button>
        <button type="button " class="btn item categItem my-1 ">
            <p>Women Role</p>
        </button>
        <button type="button " class="btn item categItem my-1 ">
            <p>Supportive Approach</p>
        </button>
        <button type="button " class="btn item categItem my-1 ">
            <p>Society Role</p>
        </button>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```css
    .styleCategItem {
        border: 1px solid #a93a8c;
        background-color: rgba(169, 58, 140, 0.1);
        border-radius: 3px;
        box-shadow: none !important;
    }

    .styleCategItem>p:before {
        content: '\f00c';
        font-family: FontAwesome;
        font-size: 8px;
        margin-right: 5px;
        padding: 1px 3px;
        color: white;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background-color: #a93a8c;
    }
    
    .categItem p {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        margin: auto;
    }
```

**Javascript**

```js
    var x = document.querySelectorAll(".categItem");

    for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].addEventListener('click', styleCategItem)
    }

    function styleCategItem(event) {
        event.currentTarget.classList.toggle("styleCategItem")
    }
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you'd add your Slick options to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using the Slick option `infinite: true` which clones a number of slides and adds them to the front and back of your slideshow to seamlessly wrap when you scroll. If you inspect the markup you can see these slides with the class `slick-cloned`.

When you click the button on an "original" slide, it adds the class to that button. When Slick decides to show the cloned slide, the button on that slide has not been changed and displays in the old style.

One quick thing to try is to wrap each button in a `<div>` so that Slick will apply its classes to the div instead of the button (e.g. `slick-cloned`). This may allow the cloned slide to pick up your content change, but I haven't tested it.

If that doesn't work, you could add a unique data attribute to each button (e.g. `data-id="1"`, `data-id="2"` ...), which will then be included in the matching cloned slide. On click, you could then select all elements with the matching data attribute and toggle `styleCategItem` on them. Something like:

```js
function styleCategItem(event) {
    var id = event.currentTarget.dataset.id;
    var matches = document.querySelectorAll('[data-id="' + id '"]');

    if (matches) {
        matches.forEach(match => match.classList.toggle("styleCategItem"));
    }
}
```